# Getting randoms with probability one third

Tags: random, probability

Having 1-bit random generator (which gives one or zero), create a function which will return 0, 1 or 2 with EQUAL probability.

Comment: Well, I can propose different solutions for just selecting one number from a range and in practice they would be sufficient giving numbers with *almost* equal probabilites. But this is a theoretical question and I cannot find a strict solution.

Comment: Ask yourself the question: If I generate some number of random bits, do I *need* to assign either `0`, `1`, or `2` to *every* possible outcome? Is there something else I could do instead?

Comment: One of the possible solutions: we can easily generate 0..3 using 2 bits; So, we do this and if we have the result of 0..2 we use it, if we have 3 we repeat the action again until we get 0..2. This seems to have right probability but if the signle bit random operation takes any amount of time (in practice it always does), the whole operation's time is not limited in theory. So now the question if this possible in a limited amount of time.

Comment: @eigenchris I think I cannot catch your  idea.. if we discard some output, it will still influence on resulting probability

Comment: That's exactly the answer you want! I'll add an answer just to explain the details.

Comment: The only way to get exactly 1/3 is rejection sampling. You can get close enough, though, by just using lots of bits (say, 32) and mod. Depends on the application whether you need to be exact or not.

Answer (score 2):

As the OP already deduced in the comments, the solution is to generate two random bits and do the following:

- if we get `00`, return `0` (25% chance)
- if we get `01`, return `1` (25% chance)
- if we get `10`, return `2` (25% chance)
- if we get `11`, generate the two random bits again (25% chance)

---

Now, there are two issues issues worth thinking about.

1. What if the program runs forever?

This is possible **in theory**, but in practice this won't happen. We would need to generate the sequence `11`, `11`, `11`, `11`,... forever.

Since getting `11` only has a 25% chance of happening, getting two `11`'s in a row would have a 6.25% of happening because `0.25*0.25 = 0.0625`. Each successive `11` adds another multiplying factor of `0.25` to the probability. Generating ten `11`'s before getting a real answer has a probability of about `1e-6` (one in a million), and this function is so fast, that's not an issue even if it did happen.

2. Does regenerating the two bits affect the 1/3 probability we want?

The answer is **no**. Generating two sets of random bits can be assumed to be **independent processes**. That means that knowing the answer to the first two bits tells us nothing about the answer to the next two bits.

When we decide to start the generation procedure again, it's as if we had never done it in the first place, since the last result we got is independent of the next one.

(In reality, this isn't true, since random number generators are deterministic under the hood, but a good uniform RNG will have this independence property when tested repeatedly).

Comment: "on average, there is about a 44% chance you will need to re-run the procedure at least once to generate a random number" not clear.. for generating one random number it should be 25%

Comment: Sorry, that remark was irrelevant and possibly confusing, so I removed it. That was the probability of redoing the experiment **at least** once. So it is the probability of redoing once plus the probability of redoing it twice plus the probability of redoing it three times... etc. All these probabilities add up to a number greater than 25%. I may have made an error in that calculation, however... it looks like it is closer to 33%. But it's not a very important fact, so I would ignore it if it confuses you.